# Finding if a specific character exists at a specific index

Tags: java

so I'm trying to figure out how to create a condition for my decision structure. I'm making a program that converts military time to conventional time. When times are entered, they must be in a XX:XX format, where X equals a digit. I'm wondering, how can I make a validation that checks to make sure that ":" always exists as a colon and is in the same spot?

Answer (score 0):

`myString.charAt(5) == ':'`

Just change 5 to whatever you need, and check string length before you do this, so you don't ask for something past the end of a short string.

Answer (score 0):

You could search the string with `indexOf()`, which returns the index at which the character is found. This will check if a colon is in the string and if it's in the right position.

```
if("10:00".indexOf(':') == 2)
  // do something
```

It will return -1 if the value is not found. Check out [the java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer for it

Suppose you had string that contains XX:XX

```
yourString="XX:XX"
yourString.contains(":") - return true  - if exists
```

":" takes the 3rd position. So it will be 2(0,1,2)

```
yourString.charAt(2) == ':'
```

Together , it will be

```
if(yourString.contains(":") && yourString.charAt(2) == ':'){
//your logic here
}else{
```

something here
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach to that,

```
String[] test = new String[] { "00:00", "NN:NN", "12,13", "12:13" };
for (String fmt : test) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < fmt.length(); i++) {
        char c = fmt.charAt(i);
        if (i == 2) {
            if (c != ':') { // here is the colon check.
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            // This checks for digits!
            if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
                isValid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fmt + " is " + isValid);
}
```

Output is

```
00:00 is true
NN:NN is false
12,13 is false
12:13 is true
```

Answer (score 0):

@WillBro posted a good answer but I give you another option:

```
myString.indexOf(":") == 5
```

With indexOf you can also look for full String inside a String.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

But for string format validations I suggest you to use Regular Expresions.

Here's a full example that does what you want to do:

http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-time-in-24-hours-format-with-regular-expression/